# Ruby on Rails locales utf-8 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

I allready have problems with utf-8 encoding in my ror app ...

some are fixed now. But some are still left.

I have now an utf-8 force in my layout

But still have problems with German special chars (ä, ö, ü). In my /config/locales/de.yml I have lots of them. In the File they look nice :) tested with rubymine and nano.

But when I start the app it crashes. The yml is encoded in utf-8 ..

I've also tried this:

```
f\xC3\xBCr --> should be für
```

always got this:

incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Does anyone have some hints for me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the encoding of the app is set to UTF-8.

Are you sure that RubyMine saves your file with UTF-8? 
You can add 
`# encoding: UTF-8` to the top of your files to assure it is set. (Not sure if this works in .yml)

**Edit**:
If you have pasted any text into the file it may still contain wrong encoding.

- Move the de.yml out of the project.
- Create a new file de.yml

  `de: 
    first_translation: Ich möchten ein bisschen Müsli`

If this works, then you need to rewrite everything from the old file, no copying!

Comment: yes i've set the encoding of rubymine to utf8. `# encoding: UTF-8`  is set already. in yml dosn't have any effect ..

Comment: Can you add full error message from when you are starting app?

Comment: I've added it in question. The error comes from line 2, there is something loaded from the locales yml

Comment: I think you should try to create a new `/config/locales/de.yml`without copying anything, start off with just a few and try it out.

Comment: Just touch de.yml or something special?

Comment: Nothing special, just add your first translated string and move your old file out of the app.